# How to manage production and debug keys in android app?

Tags: android

I am using various services in my android app for which I need userIDs and keys. Now I can store all of the keys in my string.xml file. However, since I have two different environments (production and debug) in server, i need to figure out a way of maintaining two different sets of keys based on environment. 
Is there a standard way of maintaining keys for android app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for gradle feature called `build variants`. This will let you have i.e. different `string.xml` for release build and different for debug ones. See docs:

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Build variants are specific builds that you can produce from Gradle,
>   based around shared core source code. While a standard app may have a
>   debug and release build type, you can expand on this by adding flavor
>   dimensions.

Read official guideline about **[Configuring Gradle Builds](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)**

1. **[Using Gradle Build Variants](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-gradle-build-variants--cms-25005)**

Comment: Thanks for the briliant link

Comment: Move ahead .Happy coding